# Instance of fractional [Char] required for definition?

Tags: string, haskell

This is simple code designed to take a decimal number and return a string representing the equivalent in binary.

```
b2d :: Int -> String

b2d 1 = "1"
b2d x = show (x `mod` 2) ++ b2d  x/2
```

However, when I try to run this through hugs, it gives me an error:

```
:3 - Instance of fractional [Char] required for definition of b2d
```

I don't know what this means. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Cheers.

Comment: Your first definition of b2d looks wrong. The function does not take two arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/` is the fractional division operator.  For integers, you need to use `div` (and add parentheses as newacct mentioned):

```
b2d x = show (x `mod` 2) ++ b2d (x `div` 2)
```

For extra efficiency points, use `divMod` to only perform one division:

```
b2d x = let (q,r) = x `divMod` 2
        in show r ++ b2d q
```

Answer (score 9):

you probably wanted (function calls have higher precedence than operators):

```
b2d (x/2)
```

also your first case should probably not take 2 arguments